# How to generate JHipster source files multiple times using a loop?

Tags: node.js, jhipster, yeoman

In generator-jhipster repository, specifically files.js in ../generators/server/files.js, it generates java source files and directories based on some conditions.

For example:

```
  {
            condition: generator => generator.databaseType === 'cassandra',
            path: SERVER_MAIN_SRC_DIR,
            templates: [
                {
                    file: 'package/config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java',
                    renameTo: generator => `${generator.javaDir}config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java`
                }
            ]
   }
```

This will take the template file CassandraConfiguration.java.ejs in the package/config/cassandra directory and generate the java source file CassandraConfiguration.java upon running the jhipster application successfully.

My question: is it possible to generate multiple CassandraConfiguration.java files (suppose with different names, such as: CassandraConfiguration0.java, CassandraConfiguration1.java, etc...) inside this template with a "LOOP"? I know I could run a loop with make directories (mkdirp), but I'm not sure how to apply it on making files, because it wouldn't let me create a loop inside the templates: [].

**Is this possible?** (I'm not familiar with the syntax of yeoman):

```
  {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            condition: generator => generator.databaseType === 'cassandra',
            path: SERVER_MAIN_SRC_DIR,
            templates: [
                {
                    file: 'package/config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java',
                    renameTo: generator => `${generator.javaDir}config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration[i].java`
                }
             ]
         }
   }
```

This should generate: CassandraConfiguration0.java, CassandraConfiguration1.java and CassandraConfiguration2.java respectively.

Comment: If it's for configuration classes, it would be simpler to loop inside the template to create mutliple beans.

Comment: I'm not looping inside the template classes, I wan't to loop in files.js to generate multiple files.

Comment: I updated the post with an example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong because you're trying to use imperative style in a declarative object (serverFiles).

You should rather create a loop to add entries to `serverFiles` array.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let entry = {
        condition: generator => generator.databaseType === 'cassandra',
        path: SERVER_MAIN_SRC_DIR,
        templates: [
            {
                file: 'package/config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration.java',
                renameTo: generator => `${generator.javaDir}config/cassandra/CassandraConfiguration${i}.java`
            }
        ]
     };
     serverFiles.db.push(entry);
 }
```

Comment: I believe we're pushing into serverFiles.{array}.push(entry), since serverFiles is an object. TypeError: serverFiles.push is not a function. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I did not test this code but you got the idea. I fixed it.

Comment: Hello Gael, just one more question regarding this issue. How would I pass CassandraConfiguration${i} so that it matches the corresponding class name in the file template (.ejs)? For example, CassandraConfiguration0.java => public class CassandraConfiguration0 {}, and so on...

Comment: Since we're generating multiple files, i'm not sure how to make each file name matches with its corresponding class name. If it were just one name, I could simply set it like this: <%=name%>.

Comment: I don't know, this is why my initial suggestion was simpler: one configuration class defining multiple beans. Alternatively you could define inner classes.

Comment: I didn't say it was not possible, I just said that I didn't know.

Comment: So you're saying if I were to generate multiple files under one configuration class; (CassandraConfiguration.java.ejs), it's not possible to have each file name mapped to the corresponding class names?

Comment: Alright, would you happen to know where I could get help on this issue?

Comment: Regarding your initial suggestion, would it generate multiple files under one configuration class as well? What do you mean by defining multiple beans?

Comment: My question, to be more precise, is to generate multiple CassandraConfiguration files, with different names, say CassandraConfiguration0.java, CassandraConfiguration1.java, etc... under "CassandraConfiguration.java.ejs" and have each file names, such as: CassandraConfiguration0.java => public class CassandraConfiguration0 {}, CassandraConfiguration1.java => public class CassandraConfiguration1 {}, etc...

Comment: Read the code, I suppose that you could use template options or context, look at how 'config/liquibase/fake-data/table.csv' is generated. Your question about multiple beans makes me wonder whether you know enough Spring Boot to generate code for it.